# Open a webpage without using webview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'd like to open a webpage using the webbrowser on the device. Right now I use a WebView, but I want to let the user choose between Chrome, Safari or any other webbrowser currently on the device.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 15):

```
var url = "http://www.google.com";
Device.OpenUri(new Uri(url));
```

And this uses the default browser to open the url.

Source: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/94202#Comment_94202

API Docs: [Xamarin.Forms.Device.OpenUri](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.OpenUri/p/System.Uri/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this code:

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("http://www.google.com");
var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, uri); 
StartActivity (intent);
```

And the compact version:

```
StartActivity (new Intent (Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("http://www.google.com")));
```

Comment: I tried this before I found another solution, but this requires an activity. Since I want to use a static method this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution ,

```
WebView web_view;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Social);


        web_view = FindViewById<WebView> (Resource.Id.webView);
        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        web_view.SetWebViewClient (new HelloWebViewClient ());
        web_view.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
        web_view.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
        web_view.LoadUrl ("http://www.facebook.com");


    }

    public class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, string url)
        {
            view.LoadUrl (url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I think it's the default web browser who open the webpage that you want.

Try to see this way.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. It is a restatement of the question.